# $\int\chi_I$ or $\int\chi_Idx$ for length of interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\chi$ represents a characteristic function, then which notation is technically correct or are they both valid if I want to the integral to represent the legnth of $I$?

$\int\chi_I$ or $\int\chi_Idx$?

Comment: Sometimes people leave off the measure in the integral, but technically you need it for the integral to make sense.  My calc students always leave off the dx -- drives me nuts.

Comment: As D.B. said, the two notations are equivalent but people may omit the measure when it is clearly implied. You may also clarify that the measure will always be $\mathrm{d}x$ and that you will omit it from now on (in a text).

Comment: The second should surely be $\int\chi_I(x)\,dx$.